# How to manually invoke Link in React-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component that receives through props a `<Link/>` object from **react-router**. Whenever the user clicks on a 'next' button inside this component I want to invoke `<Link/>` object manually.

Right now, I'm using *refs* to access the **backing instance** and manually clicking on the 'a' tag that `<Link/>` generates.

**Question:** Is there a way to manually invoke the Link (e.g. `this.props.next.go`)?

This is the current code I have:

```
//in MasterPage.js
var sampleLink = <Link to="/sample">Go To Sample</Link>
<Document next={sampleLink} />

//in Document.js
...
var Document = React.createClass({
   _onClickNext: function() {
      var next = this.refs.next.getDOMNode();
      next.querySelectorAll('a').item(0).click(); //this sounds like hack to me
   },
   render: function() {
      return (
         ...
         <div ref="next">{this.props.next} <img src="rightArrow.png" onClick={this._onClickNext}/></div>
         ...
      );
   }
});
...
```

This is the code I would like to have:

```
//in MasterPage.js
var sampleLink = <Link to="/sample">Go To Sample</Link>
<Document next={sampleLink} />

//in Document.js
...
var Document = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         ...
         <div onClick={this.props.next.go}>{this.props.next.label} <img src="rightArrow.png" /> </div>
         ...
      );
   }
});
...
```

Answer (score 319, accepted):

## React Router v6.8 - React 18+ (updated 02/24/2023)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function StackOverflowExample() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleOnClick = () => navigate('/sample');

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate

## React Router v6 - React 17+

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function StackOverflowExample() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => navigate('/sample', {replace: true}), [navigate]);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Note: For this answer, the one major change between v6 and v5 is `useNavigate` is now the preferred React hook. `useHistory` is deprecated and not recommended.

## React Router v5 - React 16.8+ with Hooks

If you're leveraging [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), you can take advantage of the `useHistory` API that comes from React Router v5.

```
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function StackOverflowExample() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleOnClick = useCallback(() => history.push('/sample'), [history]);

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleOnClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Another way to write the click handler if you don't want to use `useCallback`

```
const handleOnClick = () => history.push('/sample');
```

## React Router v4 - Redirect Component

The v4 recommended way is to allow your render method to catch a redirect. Use state or props to determine if the redirect component needs to be shown (which then trigger's a redirect).

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

// ... your class implementation

handleOnClick = () => {
  // some action...
  // then redirect
  this.setState({redirect: true});
}

render() {
  if (this.state.redirect) {
    return <Redirect push to="/sample" />;
  }

  return <button onClick={this.handleOnClick} type="button">Button</button>;
}
```

Reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

## React Router v4 - Reference Router Context

You can also take advantage of `Router`'s context that's exposed to the React component.

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.shape({
    history: PropTypes.shape({
      push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      replace: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }).isRequired,
    staticContext: PropTypes.object
  }).isRequired
};

handleOnClick = () => {
  this.context.router.push('/sample');
}
```

This is how `<Redirect />` works under the hood.

Reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Redirect.js#L46,L60

## React Router v4 - Externally Mutate History Object

If you still need to do something similar to v2's implementation, you can create a copy of `BrowserRouter` then expose the `history` as an exportable constant. Below is a basic example but you can compose it to inject it with customizable props if needed. There are noted caveats with lifecycles, but it should always rerender the Router, just like in v2. This can be useful for redirects after an API request from an action function.

```
// browser router file...
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Router } from 'react-router';

export const history = createHistory();

export default class BrowserRouter extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Router history={history} children={this.props.children} />
  }
}

// your main file...
import BrowserRouter from './relative/path/to/BrowserRouter';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

// some file... where you don't have React instance references
import { history } from './relative/path/to/BrowserRouter';

history.push('/sample');
```

Latest `BrowserRouter` to extend: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js

## React Router v2

Push a new state to the `browserHistory` instance:

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';
// ...
browserHistory.push('/sample');
```

Reference: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

Comment: hashHistory.push('/sample'); if you are using hashHistory instead of browserHistory

Comment: this is especially useful in the material-ui library as using containerElement={<Link to="/" />} doesn't always invoke the link

Comment: I believe browserHistory is going away in react-router v4

Comment: @JamesGentes I updated this to reflect v4 changes. I just recently migrated and use v4 for web and react native. Let me know if you see any issues.

Comment: Note with the redirect option you must specify push (ie <Redirect push />). By default it will do a replace which is not at all the same as manually invoking a Link

Comment: I just wanted to add an "active" css to the Link - I dont want to refactor the whole thing. :(

Comment: @jokab you can use <NavLink /> instead of <Link /> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js

Comment: Redirect is not working for me, but aw04 solution with withRouter is more simple and working

Comment: After redirect, this.state.redirect remain true and instead of button display, it is null component as redirect do not render any DOM.

Comment: if you use react hooks, you can consider useHistory hook

Comment: I updated the answer with the latest Hooks impl. This is the standard I use day-to-day on my own projects

Comment: This answer is outdated for v6, see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/70137765/2052752

Comment: answered updated for v6!

Comment: updated answer for 2023 standards... the cool thing about this post is you can also see the evolution of React. I haven't used `PropTypes` since 2017!

Answer (score 95):

React Router 4 includes a [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) that gives you access to the `history` object via `this.props`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.goHome = this.goHome.bind(this)
  }

  goHome() {
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    <div className="foo">
      <button onClick={this.goHome} />
    </div>
  }
}

export default withRouter(Foo)
```

Comment: This worked for me and it looks like most simple solution.

Comment: This is the best solution. I don't nderstand why it has so few votes.

Comment: yes, you can click on link few times and browser back won't work. you'll need to click on browser back for a few times to really go back

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn you can add some conditional logic:
if ((this.props.location.pathname + this.props.location.search) !== navigateToPath) { ... }

Comment: after searching for one hour, this solution finally worked. Thank you!

Comment: But can someone explain why this code will not work in the mother component (App.js)?

Comment: @IonicMan I believe it won't work in `App.js` because the `this.props.history` object is only available to components being displayed under a `<Route>`.

Answer (score 25):

In the **version 5.x**, you can use [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook of `react-router-dom`:

```
// Sample extracted from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Hooks/usehistory
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/home");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution. If you add some conditional logic, you can avoid duplicate entries in the history when a user clicks the same button multiple times: `if ((routerHistory.location.pathname + routerHistory.location.search) !== navigateToPath) { routerHistory.push(navigateToPath); }`

Comment: I needed to declare `history` variable, directory invoking `useHistory().push` is not allowed by hooks rules

Comment: this seems the most modern react-ishy solution.

Comment: This is neat and off-course works for v5.x
With arrow functions one could simply further as
`onClick={ () => history.push('/home') }`

Answer (score 10):

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/bf89168acb30b6dc9b0244360bcbac5081cf6b38/examples/transitions/app.js#L50

or you can even try executing onClick this (more violent solution):

```
window.location.assign("/sample");
```

Comment: As lines of code change, your answer will be better if you copy the details and explain your answer here. Also, `assign` is not a property, it's a function.

Comment: (But you still just have a link to a specific line of a file). Please include the specific suggestion in your answer, and not just a link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @grechut. However, I want to make sure Document does not know anything about router at all. The behavior I'm expecting is: 'If the user clicks in the right arrow, invoke the next function'. The next function may be a link or not.

Comment: I have a couple of pages handled outside of React (login screens with FB and Google redirects) so I needed this in the nav for those pages since "browserHistory.push('/home');" only changed the URL, it was unable to route the pages. Thank you.

Comment: This would reload the page @grechut, not a desired behavior for an application with react router.

Comment: As many already said, this doesn't really work with Router. It will refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 4):

Answers here are outdated.

### React Router 6

`useHistory` is deprecated v6 uses the `useNavigate` hook instead.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate()

navigate(`/somewhere`, { replace: true })
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I was able to find a proper solution for that.

Now, instead of sending `<Link/>` as **prop** to Document, I send `<NextLink/>` which is a custom wrapper for the react-router Link. By doing that, I'm able to have the right arrow as part of the Link structure while still avoiding to have routing code inside Document object.

The updated code looks like follows:

```
//in NextLink.js
var React = require('react');
var Right = require('./Right');

var NextLink = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        link: React.PropTypes.node.isRequired
    },

    contextTypes: {
        transitionTo: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },

    _onClickRight: function() {
        this.context.transitionTo(this.props.link.props.to);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.link}
                <Right onClick={this._onClickRight} />
            </div>  
        );
    }
});

module.exports = NextLink;

...
//in MasterPage.js
var sampleLink = <Link to="/sample">Go To Sample</Link>
var nextLink = <NextLink link={sampleLink} />
<Document next={nextLink} />

//in Document.js
...
var Document = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
         ...
         <div>{this.props.next}</div>
         ...
      );
   }
});
...
```

**P.S**: If you are using the latest version of react-router you may need to use `this.context.router.transitionTo` instead of `this.context.transitionTo`. This code will work fine for react-router version 0.12.X.

Answer (score 2):

#### React Router 4

You can easily invoke the push method via context in v4:

`this.context.router.push(this.props.exitPath);`

where context is:

```
static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object,
};
```

Comment: Using `BrowserRouter`, my components' context object does't contain a `router` object. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Are you setting the context in the component (the second block above)?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! eventually this worked for me:  `router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired`. I don't know why it didn't work without the `isRequired` key. Also, `<Link>` seems to be able to get the `history` context, but I couldn't replicate it.

Comment: Interesting one - if you put up a codepen I could help you debug it if you are still stuck

Comment: It seems like you can use `this.props.history.push()` in React Router v4.  I only found this by inspecting the props that React Router passes in though.  It seems to work but I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to `extend` the `Link` component to utilise some of the logic in it's `onClick()` handler, here's how:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// Extend react-router-dom Link to include a function for validation.
class LinkExtra extends Link {
  render() {
    const linkMarkup = super.render();
    const { validation, ...rest} = linkMarkup.props; // Filter out props for <a>.
    const onclick = event => {
      if (!this.props.validation || this.props.validation()) {
        this.handleClick(event);
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Failed validation");
      }
    }

    return(
      <a {...rest} onClick={onclick} />
    )
  }
}

export default LinkExtra;
```

Usage

```
<LinkExtra to="/mypage" validation={() => false}>Next</LinkExtra>
```

Answer (score -1):

again this is JS :)  this still works ....

```
var linkToClick = document.getElementById('something');
linkToClick.click();

<Link id="something" to={/somewhaere}> the link </Link>
```