# React and React-Router: Routing through function call with params passed into the route instead of clicking <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How does one do routing with params passed into it through function calls in react-router?

For example I have this Link that when click routes to a different url with parameters passed in:

```
<Link key={category.name} to={`/category/${category.name}`} params={{category: category.name}} >{category.name}</Link>
```

Suppose I want to simulate what happens when one clicks on the above link through a function call, how does one go about doing this?

```
clickHandler(){
//What function should be called to do the routing through a function call?

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router: How to manually invoke Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244731/react-router-how-to-manually-invoke-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object.

If the component which renders the `Link` is rendered by the router, then you have in `this.props` a `history` property you can use.

```
clickHandler(){
    const {
        history
        category // ??
    } = this.props
    history.push(`/category/${category.name}`);
}
```