# React Router route component stays mounted until manually refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In the code below, the Register component is staying on the page after the route changes to "/" (via `history.push("/")`). However, if I subsequently refresh the page, it disappears and everything looks how it should. Any ideas why that is happening?

```
    <Router>
      <React.Fragment>
        <Route
          path="/register"
          exact
          render={() => <Register register={this.register} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={() => (
            <Main
              posts={posts}
              post={post}
              preview={preview}
            />
          )}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    </Router>
```

Here is the register method responsible for pushing to the root route:

```
register = (e, credentials) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (authEmails.includes(credentials.email)) {
      rxcInit
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
        .then(() => {
          history.push("/");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorMessage);
          this.setState({ modalShowing: true, errorMsg: errorMessage });
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        modalShowing: true,
        errorMsg:
          "That email address isn't authorized."
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244731/react-router-how-to-manually-invoke-link.

Comment: Can you wrap your two `Route`s in a <Switch> under the `React.Fragment` tag and see if that fixes it?

Comment: @ShawnAndrews  I tried that -- same result. :/

Comment: Both your `Register` and `Main` component is wrapped with `withRouter(...)` correct?

Comment: @KevinBai Much appreciated. Redirect did the trick.