# How do I get <Link> to work with a button onClick in React with the React-Router-Dom Link import?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to get my button to navigate to an edit page for Server information I'll be providing to the route with Redux. This is written with typescript too, if that makes a difference?

I've gotten it to work if I wrap the button text like so:

```
<button onClick={this.handleEditCurrentServer}>
    <Link to={`/servers/${encodeURIComponent(this.props.IServer.name)}/edit`}>
        Edit
    </Link>
</button>
```

But the problem is that I don't want the text to be what's clicked, I want the whole button to be clickable for this route to work.

So I've tried it like this:

```
<Link to={`/servers/${encodeURIComponent(this.props.IServer.name)}/edit`}>
    <button onClick={this.handleEditCurrentServer}>
        Edit
    </button>   
</Link>
```

But unfortunately it's not using the link anymore. Is there a way to possibly add to the buttons onClick attribute?

I've hunted around on SO, and Reddit, but haven't found anything pertaining to this problem in particular.

EDIT: 
This was marked as a possible duplicate of [React-router: How to manually invoke Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244731/react-router-how-to-manually-invoke-link) but I've tried those answers, and they aren't working.

Comment: If you're using a Link, why are you using onClick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router: How to manually invoke Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244731/react-router-how-to-manually-invoke-link)

Comment: you can programmatically navigate with history push, see this for more robust answer(s): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router

Comment: @SLaks I'm kind of new to this, so .... not sure? I have the onClick updating the props, then I figured the link would navigate at the same time... but apparently not?

Comment: @mfakhrusy I did try adding this to the handleEditCurrentServer

```
        this.props.history.push(`/servers/${encodeURIComponent(this.props.IServer.name)}/edit`);
```

But it didn't work either

Comment: does the URL change but the page isn't navigating, or the button just don't do anything? @glitchwizard

Comment: You need to remove the ```Link``` component and use only the ```button``` component @glitchwizard

Comment: @mfakhrusy I did remove the `Link` component, and only used the `button`, but when I try to use the history.push I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: because you haven't use the ```withRouter``` Higher Order Component (HOC) from react-router-dom package, use them, so ```history``` props will be defined. @glitchwizard. I'm not familiar with typescript's decorator but I think you can use them too. It's the same thing as ```connect``` HOC from `react-redux` if you're familiar with it.

Comment: @mfakhrusy that fixed it! I added the withRouter to the export and it worked. Please submit that as an answer so I can mark it appropriately.