# How to ignore Material UI theme styling for component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

My button component (that is also a material UI component) already has the style I want, but when I surround it with the Link component, which is a react-dom-router component, it overrides the style of my button.
How to ignore the default style of Link?

```
<AppBar>
   <Toolbar>
      <Link to="/some-link">
          <Button>
              My Button
          </Button>
       </Link>
   </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Comment: Hi @Akira Kotsugai, could you mark one of the answers as valid if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting a Link (`<a>`) inside a Button (`<button>`), and viceversa, is not valid HTML. I would recommend you either remove the Button or you use [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router) and add `props.history.push("/some-link")` to your Button onClick handler. Like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => history.push("/some-link")}>My Button</Button>
```

Take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/new-platform-rodtj) I made. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting a button inside a `Link` (which is weird because they are both clickable elements) just use the Button with an `onClick` handler where you can manually trigger the route change.

See also [React-router: How to manually invoke Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244731/react-router-how-to-manually-invoke-link)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example given on the material ui site.  You probably don't need the router part though.

https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#ButtonRouter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

// The usage of React.forwardRef will no longer be required for react-router-dom v6.
// see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6056
const AdapterLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link innerRef={ref} {...props} />);

const CollisionLink = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <Link innerRef={ref} to="/getting-started/installation/" {...props} />
));

export default function ButtonRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Button color="primary" component={AdapterLink} to="/">
        Simple case
      </Button>
      <Button component={CollisionLink}>Avoids props collision</Button>
    </Router>
  );
}
```